# How to setup typescript generics in class constructors and functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following **base interface** (`Animal`) and **two implementations** (`Dog` and `Cat`) where each implementation has its own properties (`DogProps` and `CatProps`).

```js
interface Animal<T> {
  props: T;
  eat(): void;
}

interface DogProps {
  color: string;
  breed: string;
}

class Dog implements Animal<DogProps> {
  constructor(public readonly props: DogProps) {}
  eat() {}
}

interface CatProps {
  color: string;
  lives: number;
}

class Cat implements Animal<CatProps> {
  constructor(public readonly props: CatProps) {}
  eat() {}
}
```

Next up, I have a **simulator class** that can receive an optional initial animal (or set the default one which is a `Dog`). Users can also use the simulator to change the animal to anything else (e.g. `Cat`) at any time.
Interface `Animal<T>` is public, so the user **can define its own new implementation**, e.g. `Bird<BirdProps>` and run it through the simulator.

**I have issues with how to define the simulator** to be able to take any implementation of `Animal<T>` without knowing about `T` (properties). I tried with these two but it is not working:

```js
interface SimulatorSettings<T> {
  initialAnimal: Animal<T>;
  simulationSteps: number;
}

class SimulatorTry1<T> {
  private _animal: Animal<T>;

  constructor(settings?: Partial<SimulatorSettings<T>>) {
    // Issue 1: Type 'Dog | Animal<T>' is not assignable to type 'Animal<T>'
    this._animal = settings?.initialAnimal ?? new Dog({ color: 'white', breed: 'samoyed' });
    this.doStuff(settings?.simulationSteps ?? 100);
  }

  get animal(): Animal<T> {
    return this._animal;
  }

  setAnimal(animal: Animal<T>, settings: Omit<SimulatorSettings<T>, 'initialAnimal'>) {
    this._animal = animal;
    this.doStuff(settings.simulationSteps);
  }

  private doStuff(steps: number) {}
}

class SimulatorTry2 {
  // Issue 1: Unable to set <T> here because T is undefined
  private _animal: Animal<any>;

  // Issue 2: Unable to set "constructor<T>": Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration.
  constructor(settings?: Partial<SimulatorSettings<T>>) {
    this._animal = settings?.initialAnimal ?? new Dog({ color: 'white', breed: 'samoyed' });
    this.doStuff(settings?.simulationSteps ?? 100);
  }

  // Issue3: Unable to set "get animal<T>": An accessor cannot have type parameters.
  get animal(): Animal<T> {
    return this._animal;
  }

  setAnimal<T>(animal: Animal<T>, settings: Omit<SimulatorSettings<T>, 'initialAnimal'>) {
    this._animal = animal;
    this.doStuff(settings.simulationSteps);
  }

  private doStuff(steps: number) {}
}
```

Here is the link to the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=89&ssc=74&pln=89&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwDwAqAfMgN4BQyyADlAPbUDOAXMgQNyXIRxgAUASlYA3OsAAmnAL7lyoSLEQoAInQDmABXpMyXBHRx0orRmCig1nKgCMoECOJNmL02QhxxGjZKrXIs1DgQmBDg3uhYuHi+WgyMJBRU+iCmUACuCGBGfNRp1jjACMh2cOJ0IDgAnjTaLD7qsUwCZDJUPPzNpDIycuDQ8EjIAMK8jd6JyPqGxsipLlwFwhB1IGmY1tCu5O6e3iNg-piBwaFg4RjY+PtjCXrlqRlZUDl5BUUlZRXVtHGs17WdVrcXiCFrkHryfpKZAAZSwaQ8TxhEDAYAsjEItyooGAaNwEUurAJUWIVlm8MRwHKMMgTFYq3Wm3Bbg8XlhFN4RgIUEqAEZMboqLRgMJeCgAPpwC64InS-Ck2RJe5mR7ZRgotEgNSMAD8rA0cCgePwcMwCM5UGRqPRmKInS4VAA9I7kABJLxpFC81gESrUFAAcl8yAAPmg5ZiA-5vCA6AddsA1CA4PkUFlkGA-YHifKiAGHRmABbARgAOklcuQAF5Zhr0TrSzjjTnkDqdcgQBAAO71NR8UiTAxGVgBrvFyABgA0yFs9kcyADjDgmDolQcUakAjJVDAxbLZRpaRgMD46utWt1pcYHLR1Np3jbyF5AAZn1uuD0qGoUcgpZEcIIsr-gKExUHYYBpFAIBFiW5Z-pcZKfrWYA5nw8EyuGwHENOZ6atqrAAPKYLieCmuaSJ1hemLTgGTbAPicoBnagpUDBZYVv+1a-nK25saWB4Qcep6UdqV43lSIA0hATSIYqNQimKyACUeJ6mNJKxrBsUCAsy2yst4ZGIlyPIAEwsc6boel6rAAKrJqmGZ0MhyACoW0AoBsCBwGk6psNGyBpCA4gQDAoAOFwwqipAyAcYSmGXHgUqVEQnBcBZ7qMJ6yAmbZ9lBI5zkAETJA8mRGJihU+lmNCGsuKLQN4XkgLG8bUP6hrIOUv6DikKplVASkQDsUC8BJpZ3L16T9cJ57anqyAGka9EmjeRhWnhGLEMxoF8bFuBcbh9aNhgzaVo+nY9r4-aDtMI5jriEBTjOdgOCOS4rmu4gbu+rF8cpQmHReDbXmalJ3uprbti+b6yWlLoZZ6ADMuUpvl6ZnsghXfvGEbEJV4a-ggSBeEYkxSi1yCFnASwZtV1C1SEChllw2Pcf+gHxSSWKseBkHQbusF7TgsNUGeOaYmhcpAQl2HIRthHEWApGrZaImbUQNF0Qx-5Mfav0C+x6E4FxRu8Qb-F0IeANq2JoOjeDMkfnJkWKf9qn3vSmnQDpEJ9IogwAELAFA4hjCxXYWDC9MgJ7jJQFsOxskHIeHMcIRhJz+DJ6HtTcyVfVPC8+SFMUPCfFUNS-Mg2djDpbQgj7bjKuSdtPFxF3sq3xl8oInAWQHQ3eb5u4oMF8AIjjnElkp6jbM3UykzWIPkUYpZG6WPxMKWC-x7IFkAHJ0D2I9s5c-nWMH4jkMvRlQFeKKoR32fXRHWpR1KrAmc+yCbtOA43-bSSHsnzf03JwfOsxo4HRVmvOUG9aillfmod+IBUpAA) with the full code.

My question is: **Is this possible to do** (I assume it is) and **how to do it** without defining that `T = DogProps | CatProps` because users can create new implementations which should be supported?

```
interface BirdProps {
  wingSpan: number;
}

class Bird implements Animal<BirdProps> {
  constructor(public readonly props: BirdProps) {}
  eat() {}
}

const simulator = new SimulatorTry1();
// Color exists because the default animal is dog
const color = simulator.animal.props.color;

// Now the animal is bird, so props are BirdProps
simulator.setAnimal(new Bird({ wingSpan: 20 }), { simulationSteps: 10 });
const span = simulator.animal.props.wingSpan;
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible; TypeScript does not model arbitrary *mutation* of types.  If `sim.animal.props.color` is a `string` at some point, then you can't have it become something other than a `string` (like `undefined`) after a call to `sim.setAnimal(new Bird({wingspan:123}))`.  See [ms/TS#41339](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41339) for a suggestion to support this sort of thing. This means the whole point with `T` is moot. Do you want me to write up an answer saying this is impossible and why?  Or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are not missing anything, you got it right and you named it better than me, as a mutation of a type that has a generic `T` (used as the `props`). I've lost so many hours on this trying to make it work :D

Regarding the answer, please do. I will mark it as an accepted answer!

Comment: I just changed all the generics in SimulatorTry2 to be <any> and the code seems to be working: [Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-gue20h). Don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @shadow-lad True, it works with `any`, but I wanted to somehow use `T` so I can have support from Typescript whenever I type `simulator.animal.props` to show me what is valid there instead of `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible; TypeScript doesn't have a way to represent *mutable* types, where some operation produces a value of one type and then later the same operation produces a value of an arbitrarily different type.   It can [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of a value by gaining more information about it via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), but you're not trying to do only narrowing.  Presumably you'd want to see this happen:

```
const simulator = new SimulatorTry1();
const c0 = simulator.animal.props.color; // string
simulator.setAnimal(new Bird({ wingSpan: 20 }), { simulationSteps: 10 });
const c1 = simulator.animal.props.color // undefined, or possibly compiler error
```

But if `c0` is of type `string` then `c1` really must be of a type assignable to `string`.  It can't really be `undefined`.

---

Control flow analysis does sometimes *reset* the apparent type and therefore re-widen it, so you could imagine making a type like `unknown` and then doing a series of narrowings and resettings.  But these resettings only happen upon explicit [assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) like `simulator.animal.props.color = undefined`.  You can't make this happen via a call to `simulator.setAnimal()`.  In order to make `simulator.setAnimal()` change the apparent type of `simulator.animal.props`, it would have to be [an assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)... and these only narrow.

So we're stuck; this isn't possible.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#41339](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41339) to support mutable types.  It's currently marked as "Awaiting More Feedback", meaning they want to hear compelling use cases from the community before even thinking of implementing it.  If you think this `Simulator` use case is important, you could go there and describe it and why the available workarounds aren't acceptable.  But I don't know that it would help much.

---

The workarounds I can imagine here are to replace statefulness with immutability, at least at the type level.  That is, the call to `setAnimal()` should create a *new* simulator, or it should at least *look like* it does.  For example, here's a way using an assertion method, where calling `setAnimal()` essentially invalidates the current simulator, and you need to access its `simulator` property to get the "new" one, even though there really is only one at runtime:

```
class Simulator<T = DogProps> {
  private _animal: Animal<T>;

  constructor(settings?: Partial<SimulatorSettings<T>>);
  constructor(settings: SimulatorSettings<T>) {
    this._animal = settings?.initialAnimal ?? new Dog({ color: 'white', breed: 'samoyed' });
    this.doStuff(settings?.simulationSteps ?? 100);
  }

  get animal(): Animal<T> {
    return this._animal;
  }

  setAnimal<U>(animal: Animal<U>, 
    settings: Omit<SimulatorSettings<U>, 'initialAnimal'>
  ): asserts this is {
    animal: never;
    setAnimal: never;
    simulator: Simulator<U>;
  };
  setAnimal(animal: Animal<any>, settings: SimulatorSettings<any>) {
    this._animal = animal;
    this.doStuff(settings.simulationSteps);
    this.simulator = this;
  }
  simulator: unknown;


  private doStuff(steps: number) { }
}
```

And then this is how you'd use it:

```
const sim1: Simulator = new Simulator();
const color = sim1.animal.props.color.toUpperCase();
console.log(color) // WHITE

sim1.setAnimal(new Bird({ wingSpan: 20 }), { simulationSteps: 10 });
// now you have to abandon sim1

const sim2 = sim1.simulator;
// const sim2: Simulator<BirdProps>

const span = sim2.animal.props.wingSpan.toFixed(2);
console.log(span) // "20.00"
```

---

Or you can just spawn new simulators, so there's no invalidation:

```
class Simulator<T = DogProps> {
  private _animal: Animal<T>;

  constructor(settings?: Partial<SimulatorSettings<T>>);
  constructor(settings: SimulatorSettings<T>) {
    this._animal = settings?.initialAnimal ?? new Dog({ color: 'white', breed: 'samoyed' });
    this.doStuff(settings?.simulationSteps ?? 100);
  }

  get animal(): Animal<T> {
    return this._animal;
  }

  spawnSimulator<U>(animal: Animal<U>, 
    settings: Omit<SimulatorSettings<U>, 'initialAnimal'>): Simulator<U> {
    return new Simulator({ initialAnimal: animal, ...settings });
  }

  private doStuff(steps: number) { }
}
```

And this is how you'd use it:

```
const sim1 = new Simulator();
// const sim1: Simulator<DogProps>
const color = sim1.animal.props.color.toUpperCase();
console.log(color) // WHITE

const sim2 = sim1.spawnSimulator(new Bird({ wingSpan: 20 }), { simulationSteps: 10 });
// const sim2: Simulator<BirdProps>

const span = sim2.animal.props.wingSpan.toFixed(2);
console.log(span) // "20.00"

// you can still access sim1
console.log(sim1.animal.props.breed.toUpperCase()) // "SAMOYED"
```

---

In either case you're giving up on the idea of unsupported mutable types and instead using TypeScript's normal immutable types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwDwAqAfMgN4BQyyADlAPbUDOAXMgQNyXIRxgAUASlYA3OsAAmnAL7lyoSLEQoAInQDmABXpMyXBHRx0orRmCig1nKgCMoECOJNmL02QhxxGjZKrXIs1DgQmBDg3uhYuHi+WgyMJBRU+iCmUACuCGBGfNRp1jjACMh2cOJ0IDgAnjTaLD7qsUwCZMgyVDz8zaSt5DJy4NDwSMgAwryN3onI+obGyKkuXAXCEHUgaZjW0K7k7p7eY2D+mIHBoWDhGNj4hxMJeuWpGVlQOXkFRSVlFdW0cay3WpdHrtXiCFoyPryQZKZAAIWAUHEE10VAA7hYAMrUOAgVjrTbbXpuDxeeGI8THU4hMJoK5RBFIu6o6aPMzPbK5fKFYo8b5VGr-clMoEQrgdcHdSGyfoKIYoTFYNIeF6YiBgMAWRiEe5UUDATW4CLXVjGqLEKzzJUq4DlTGQJj4jZbKA7EBwEKMHHDADqRgA1nB6GkQOJUF5oJryro9KTvIrMMreEZCMgALz1TS1XVUGrAYS8FAAfVxkRwpvp+AtslzrJS7My2UY6s1IDUjAA-KwNEHDfgE0nVS2tTqiAJLUk2elG69mxqtawByqjGr523tcQulxa2AABbARgAOhLlfT82H647h-1fbNOGQHY7yBAEDRmb43RmRlYAHI0fvIB-AAaZBbHsRxkB-RgPToSoHB-Vpx23XM9wPQ8yntNIYBgPg51bdsr0Ya1eFtEB7QgHRH2QABGAAGWikNrPpazUdVkFLa5BArMsdRZWs7DANIoBAZBUKPE8ywnHpkLnO88AAVSIPgONwbjrgUogQLwhdkAAeUwA08CXZMoFXfDtUUkCfxvYAjUrH8x1YfZI28MT-EmZCqBU8tnwgFZXU888wDvfE-KJWsqCIxNlzmYyXg0qSpCk2TK2Uys1KiXFKk0oLzMXYihzXds8Cysc+JQ-dxO8s9vKkqgxPQuhMOw3CL3bQ8osHUjyKaOrRMqjqCqMM8xMSmShrmEN-RAOg0RATga1zWh80LZAMMElrTAotZnWgYE2mkyd6ytTBqPy6KTLPF83zi7JGLrUxWVmM8ouow9vMPP4mEPL8oEPLJ5OoahoDGZtBEtZJGAMCBD0MNQ+F+5oAHokeQH0AAkAEkCAAUUW16OvVO8+Gu4VxA-ZAMTbbFcVYAAmWjEJA7pOptO0HTqOjEMtFHn1m5BKjoNJkF3OAVlEuh2OsXFvhO6jFsho4orpl6sDe1mTJ51HFZOunzsHFNGWRbMFbZeYcREjNlfeytPtqQ8qbUGmQH+ugADFgAADwcPg6fuyHodh9RcIt5HUYAIgZw96PDmU+l2ONkFuqBUwzGJsxZZaC0gZAJJNOkeOrB562nF5WqKztu17Wz+wmsyR2IMcIanDlZzaupk-r9cdS3HcBrz3AXvbq8bLsssHyfUnfAp37f3-A0IGA0C7AcX9oMwWD4O55CGvWrCcO0y9BouqMyI5ieaPo+7mOQVijm8riC-U4hyoEoSRIagecEtG+vTgObk4aTSmWDK+BLK5R0vpQynd24aSsqPHAd4HJCCThNDSr91Tv18jdCaFMEEhXYpWECh4SGH3bNvKgN8s6rT3ptDmTpCRQH2sSXYZtXpXVfKgk+d1OC8x1q9fWMVogNBNjrX6qtTo2zLHbOIP0DBGFdoDYGUBQYQHBqwlIgc4YI3kUw5AvMMbYzxhox6ysJHqxxAA3BpMjYU0ds7emjMpACGZidLq7NtqsC5s43h2s2FYD1lwg2KcjZ3DcGwi2Ei6ZSOuDI769iLauw9t7cmftOAByCEHeGf8QBh2QJHWi0daKx3ILzQWwsEC4nmJqHA95EBIDJK9ExWjg4Ew+l9I8YEHCKKBiDTwaiBB5PDpiVAABZXSABNHGygSlAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot @jcalz! I really like your second workaround that returns a new class - it has cleaner usage compared to the first one with the class property `simulator`.